# DFS with queue, BFS with stack

Tags: stack, queue, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

As in the question, is there anyway to implement DFS with queue and BFS with stack? 
I couldn't find any related discussion about it.

Answer (score 1):

Why would you want to do that? In practice, I do not think it will work quite well or if it is even possible, however, if it is I think it will be very inefficient. Why? Well, we need to keep track of vertices in certain ways with these algorithms. Let's use a queue for DFS for example, while running your algorithm, at some point you run into a situation where the vertex/node you are looking at cannot visit any other node, you will need to go back to a previous node but we can not retrieve elements at certain indexes of the queue except say you add that to your implementation which then makes it not a queue. Such will occur for BFS with stacks, you will have to remove all elements from the stack while searching. So why do that?